# How to select a content from dropdown and be the first one to be appeared in Boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to select the content I click and this content has to be the first one to be selected. Like the select option.

This is the img.

[image: name of the dropdown]

I'm not quite sure how to make this, this is my demo: http://jsbin.com/jazej/1#0

Basically the part of the code is this.

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" id="selectCard" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Card <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="indexCards">
      <li class="active"><a href="#0">Card 1</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#0">Card 2</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#0">Card 3</a></li>
      <li class=""><a href="#0">Card 4</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

But I can't get no event fire or something when I do $('#indexCards'). Any idea about this?

Comment: This Linked dropdown not a form select button

Comment: Show the relevant html and JS..

Comment: @Hushme so it's not posibble then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : Read text of the clicked anchor inside `indexCards`  and put it in `selectCard`

```
$(function(){
  $('#indexCards li a').click(function(){
     $('.active').removeClass('active');
     $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
     var text = $(this).text();
     $('#selectCard').html(text+'<b class="caret"></b>');
  });
});
```

Comment: This works, thanks, just wondering why the question goes with a - less reputation. Here is a demo for someone who is interested: http://jsbin.com/jazej/1/edit

Comment: This is may be that you have not shared the html code initially. Anyways happy to help you .. if you are satisfied with solution provided then you can accept this answer by clicking a right mark below downvote button.

Comment: Thanks!, if you consider the question is useful could you vote up the question.